# How To Set Multiple Files In Html Input By Default?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If we have single `file` input then we set it with

```html
 <input type='file' value='/bla/bla/bla.jpg'>
```

I have urls for example:

```js
var images = ['http://bla.com/bla.jpg','http://bla.com/bla2.jpg']
```

How can we set multiple images from urls to `file` input?

```html
<input type='file' multiple>
```

Comment: Please briefly explain your question

Comment: If you want to allow multiple file type to be allowed try using something like `accept="image/png, image/jpeg"`

Comment: Do you want select multiple files in `<input type="file">`

Comment: You cannot do this due to security reasons.
Please see this-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Answer (score 0):

Note: The multiple attribute works with the following input types: email, and file.

For `<input type="file">`: to select multiple files, hold down the `CTRL` or `SHIFT` key while selecting.

And when we want to take file input by default, then we cannot do it. It means we cannot set a value to a file input due to some security reasons in HTML.